# how to uninstall Angular IDE plugin from Eclipse Oxygen?

Tags: angular, eclipse

I have hit the 8 day limit of the free  license but need to keep working.

- I have tried the Uninstall option for the Eclipse Marketplace Installed screen but this failed to remove the Angular-IDE.
- I then Uninstalled Webclipse and this still failed to remove it.
- I opened a command line terminal on windows and manually ran the npm uninstall angular-ide command.

The word Angular (without the icon) still displays on menu bar which leads me to believe it is still not uninstalled. Also there are side effects in eclipse - which indicates it has probably damaged some eclipse files.

So what is needed in order to manually completely remove Angular IDE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you uninstalled Angular IDE. If you had the Angular perspective open (not necessarily in focus) in the workspace, it would still be there (hence the name "Angular" without the icon, though this is in the perspective area not the menu bar) though any Angular IDE views would show errors.

Check Help->About->Installation Details for installed software, to see if it has been uninstalled. You should also see no Preferences pages for Webclipse.

Try opening with a fresh workspace then import projects from your old workspace. If you still see odd behavior, then reinstall eclipse for a completely clean configuration (this is quick if you are installing an eclipse package, rather than using the installer).

(By the way, you don't say why you can't continue working, when the 8 day limit is hit. Certainly, you won't be able to use Angular IDE functions but you will be able to use the rest of eclipse - you will need to close the Angular perspective - until Angular IDE functionality is available again next month)

Comment: Ended up reinstalling and importing into a fresh workspace. Something else had interfered with my projects, I suspect another eclipse plugin that I un-installed corrupted the projects somehow.